# Display family purchases in iTunes library

Tags: itunes, family-sharing

I just set up family sharing for purchases. Is there some way of showing the purchases in the iTunes library like the person own purchases appear so that they can be streamed?

Comment: Yes, in heaven.

Comment: Yes, in heaven.